# Delete a column in Notepad++ with pipe '|' delimeter

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have this file with format:

```
Line 1467|XXXXX| YYYYY
Line 146137|XXXXX| YYYYY
Line 14617|XXXXX| YYYYY
Line 149367|XXXXX| YYYYY
Line 15467|XXXXX| YYYYY
Line 1467|XXXXX| YYYYY
Line 14267|XXXXX| YYYYY
```

I need to delete the first column, so I need to only have:

```
XXXXX| YYYYY
```

What replace options and regex can I use to delete the first column?

P.S: Line << Text

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Replace dialog box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. Enter this in the *Find what:* box `^[^|]+\|([^\r\n]+)`
3. Enter this in the *Replace with:* box `\1`
4. Click the *Regular expression* radio button
5. Click the *Replace All* button

However, be careful not to hit Replace All more than once, since your second column will then become the first column.

In the *Find what:* box,

- the first `^` instructs it to start at the beginning of the line
- the square brackets `[ ]` instruct it to look for a set of characters

  - the caret `^` inside the square brackets instruct it to look for any chars **not** in the set
  - so when it comes to the pipe char `|`, it looks for any char that is not a pipe char
  - the plus sign `+` looks for one or more occurrences of what the square brackets find
- since the pipe char `|` has special meaning in regular expressions, we have to precede it with a backslash `\`
- parentheses `( )` group and save things. So we'll save any chars found between parentheses

  - the square brackets `[ ]` instruct it to look for a set of characters
  - the caret `^` inside the square brackets instruct it to look for any chars **not** in the set
  - a carriage return `\r` and a line feed `\n` end a line, so look for any char that does not end the line
  - the plus sign `+` looks for one or more occurrences of what the square brackets find

So it will look for anything up to the pipe + the pipe char, but it will only save any char in the rest of the line **after** the first pipe.

In the *Replace with:* field:

- a backslash `\` followed by a number `1` represents what was saved in the first set of parentheses